# How to determine 'did' or 'did not' on something

Tags: python, nlp, sentiment-analysis, textblob

What's the straightforward way to distinguish between this two:

1. `the movie received critical acclaim`
2. `the movie did not attain critical acclaim`.

Seems to me 'sentiment analysis' of nlp could do it for me. So I'm using `Textblob` [sentiment analysis](https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/quickstart.html#sentiment-analysis). But both sentences' `polarity` is `0.0`.

Comment: From the machine learning point of view, it is similar to `sentiment analysis`. They are both `classification` problems but keep in mind your labels convey different supervision, they are showing if the verb is positive or negative.

Comment: what's the rough framework towards solving this? i'm currently learning NLP and 'nltk' from zero

Comment: Can you provide labeled data for your task? @kyw

Comment: Do you get exactly `0.0` for `subjectivity` too? That suggests your code is not set up correctly, and it is not actually parsing anything.

Comment: @meti I don't have labeled data of any sorts.. sounds like i have to train some kinda models?

Comment: hi @DarrenCook. The `subjectivity` weren't `0.0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For *simple* in your case, you can use **flair** which is based on **LSTM** model, that takes sequences of words into account for prediction.

*1. installing flair*

```
!pip3 install flair
```

*2. code*

```
import flair
flair_sentiment = flair.models.TextClassifier.load('en-sentiment')

sentence1 = 'the movie received critical acclaim'
sentence2 = 'the movie did not attain critical acclaim'

s1 = flair.data.Sentence(sentence1)
flair_sentiment.predict(s1)
s1_sentiment = s1.labels
print(s1_sentiment)

s2 = flair.data.Sentence(sentence2)
flair_sentiment.predict(s2)
s2_sentiment = s2.labels
print(s2_sentiment)
```

*3. result*

```
print(s1_sentiment)
[POSITIVE (0.9995)]

print(s2_sentiment)
[NEGATIVE (0.9985)]
```

For more details about **flair**, you can visit [this github repo](https://github.com/flairNLP/flair).

Answer (score 0):

It requires negation handling capabilities. For example, [wink-nlp](https://github.com/winkjs/wink-nlp) supports negation handling. You can checkout the code with this example at [runkit](https://runkit.com/sanjaya/61b63be87397520008bb8c91).